# read and write file

Tags: c++, file-io

I wrote a program which should read a text from a file and after that it should write word frequencies in a different file.how can I do it?

Comment: Write a computer program in an unspecified language.

Comment: i wrote program i have a method which name is treePrint but i don't know how I can use files in my main class

Comment: You really have to be more specific. Which programming language are you using?

Comment: void treePrint(node *p)
{

 if(p!=NULL)

  treePrint(p->left);
 printf("%4d %s\n",p->count,p->word);

 treePrint(p->right);

Comment: this is my treePrint method..

Comment: what about searching online something like 'C++ open file' ??

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be too difficult. Just use whatever programming language you like best.